# How do you find $p(a,b|c)$ if you have the known values stated below

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

known values:
$p(a), p(b), p(c), p(a,b)$

Answer (score 2):

In a general setting, you can't because there is even no information about $c,a,b$ conditioned on one another. One formulation using Bayes Rule could be the following:
$$p(a,b|c)=\frac{p(a,b,c)}{p(c)}=\frac{p(c|a,b)p(a,b)}{p(c)}$$
you need $p(c|a,b)$ here to find what you're looking for. Also, if you know $p(a,b)$, marginals $p(a),p(b)$ doesn't give any extra information other than the joint. So, actually, you only know $p(a,b),p(c)$ in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You don't have enough information. $P(a,b|c) = \frac{P(a,b,c)}{P(c)}$, so you would need to know joint distribution of the three variables, or alternatively other conditional distributions to use [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).